# Insert two variables as lines and one variable as points in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot three different .csv columns, the 1st and 2nd as lines and the 3rd as points (only two points).
I am a begineer in R and I have the following data

- data

[image]

- code

```
    df = read.csv("conceptual_methodology.csv")
    
    ggplot(df, aes(x=time, group=1))+
      geom_line(aes(time, var_1, color = "var_1"), size = 1.2)+
      geom_line(aes(time, var_2, color = "var_2"), size = 1.2)+
      geom_point(aes(time, var_3, color = "red"), size = 3)+
      scale_y_continuous(c(0.26, 0.3), seq(0, 0.3, 0.005))+
      xlab("label_x")+
      ylab("label_y")+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.border = element_rect(color = "black"),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank())
```

The outcome is the following image: [image: Rplot]

Obviously, my code is not brilliant and I have the following problems with the result:

1. ylab does not appear
2. numbers in x axis do not appear
3. I don't understand why everything appears as line and point in the legend, and not var_1 & var_2 just lines and var_3 just point.
4. Why y axis stops at 0.295 and not 0.3 as specified in scale_y_continuous.
5. How can I change the colors of the lines and points without changing the names in the legend. For example, when I put color="red" in geom_point the name of the series becomes red in the legend.

Can someone please fix my code?

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064), share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it's easier to copy/paste the data for testing.

Comment: for point 2) remove `axis.text.x=element_blank()`

Comment: for point 1) and 4) add argument names to `scale_y_...`: `scale_y_continuous(name = "label_y", limits = c(0.26, 0.3), breaks = seq(0, 0.3, 0.005))`

Comment: lastly, for point 5) add the color outside of the `aes`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to struggle a bit with the rest of it, but very helpful advice and it looks much better now.